# Multiplicity of Irreducible Representations for Faithful Representation of Group Algebra, $\mathbb{C}G$.

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\mathbb{C}G$ its associated group algebra. The regular representation $\mathbb{C}G\subset B(\ell^2(G))$ defined by:

$$\delta^g(e_{g_2})=e_{g_1g_2},$$

contains each irreducible representation $\mathbb{C}G\subset B(V_\alpha)$ with multiplicity equal to its degree.

In the case of $\mathbb{C}S_3$, where $V_0$ is associated to trivial representation, $V_1$ to the sign representation, and $V_2$ to the degree two irreduciblee representation, the regular representation is a faithful representation of $\mathbb{C}S_3$ on $\mathbb{C}^6\cong V_0\oplus V_1\oplus V_2\oplus V_2$.

However there is also a [faithful representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898628/the-comultiplication-on-mathbbc-s-3-for-a-matrix-basis) of $\mathbb{C}S_3$ that just uses each irreducible representation once.

**Question: Do we always have a faithful representation when we just use every irreducible representation just once?**

Comment: This representation is unique up to isomorphism so you just have to figure out whether or not it's faithful. Compare its kernel to the kernel of the regular representation.

Comment: Thank you Qiaochu Yuan.

Comment: If $\rho$ and $\pi$ are two homomorphisms, then $\ker(\rho\oplus\pi)=(\ker\rho)\cap(\ker\pi)$. You can show this in the context of elementary group theory and apply it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

If $\rho$ contains all the irreducible representations, then $k(G)\subset \rho^{\oplus n}$ for some $n$. If $\rho$ were not faithful, then so would be $\rho^{\oplus n}$, contradiction.